# Internet Explorer issue with remote Vue.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js

This is quite strange. I have a set of apps, all deployed on AWS. all of them are using the same wildcard certificate. These apps are .Net, jsp, and vue.js!

The vue.js works locally with internet explorer just fine, but once deployed (TLS) I keep gettnig to a blank page, and in the dom explorer I see a message telling me that JavaScript isn'rt enabled. I verified that scripting is enabled from Internet options, but it still isn't showing any content. It shows perfectly if I'm trying on my local network, but once the applications are on different network, the application shows a blank page.

I'm using internet explorer 11

Is there a setting that needs to be changed from the windows machine itself or something more to be added?

Comment: any console errors, what version of ie?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: It's internet explorer 11 @SilvioBiasiol

Comment: Does it work remotely in other browsers?

Comment: it works on all browsers except for ie11 @Hammerbot

Answer (score 0):

there is with your internet explorer,
try this :

1. On web browser menu click "Tools" icon and select "Internet Options".
2. In the "Internet Options" window select the "Security" tab.
3. On the "Security" tab click on the "Custom level..." button.
4. When the "Security Settings - Internet Zone" dialog window opens, look for the "Scripting" section.
5. In the "Active Scripting" item select "Enable".
6. When the "Warning!" window pops out asking "Are you sure you want to change the settings for this zone?" select "Yes".
7. In the "Internet Options" window click on the "OK" button to close it.
8. Click on the "Refresh" button of the web browser to refresh the page.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, Try to create 2 sample webpages. 1st with simple JS and 2nd with vue.JS Try to host them and try to open them. check whether they are working with IE or not. If the page with Vue.JS work than we may need to focus on other possibilities. Also try to find if there are any relevant settings are available with TLS or not.